# ActiveAdmin comments on custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a custom admin page that I'm rendering through a `member_action` endpoint. I am trying to figure out how to render the active admin comments panel for the resource on that page.

Is there a helper method, or a partial I can call with the resource to render the active admin  comments on my custom page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arbre components can only be rendered within an Arbre context. The blocks for `member_action` and `collection_action` run directly within the controller and do not provide a context for Arbre components. It is possible to render an Arbre view template such as `custom_action.html.arb` and within that template `active_admin_comments_for(resource)` is available.

```
# custom_action.html.arb
active_admin_comments_for(resource)
```

A second method is to create an `Arbre::Context` within the view rendered by another template language like ERB.

```
<h2>Custom Action ERB</h2>
<%= 
  Arbre::Context.new({}, self) do
    active_admin_comments_for(resource)
  end
%>
```

This method works for all Arbre components provided by ActiveAdmin. See [`Arbre::Context`](https://github.com/activeadmin/arbre/blob/92141d29115b4898cdbb9a3a279f275daa127f9e/lib/arbre/context.rb#L37) for more information.

Answer copied from ActiveAdmin GitHub [Issue #3327](https://github.com/activeadmin/active_admin/issues/3327#issuecomment-52218898).